# Same text in UTF-8 but different in ANSI

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, culture

I have a Notepad++. The Encoding is UTF-8, in notepad I have two text

```
Thành
Thành
```

But when i use Find dialog to search "Thành" the result has only 1 result.
I change the Notepad++ encoding to ANSI. It show

```
ThÃ nh
ThaÌ€nh
```

Why are they different in ANSI ?  What should i do to make they same ?

Comment: "ANSI" is not well-defined in this context; Microsoft has in principle agreed to retire it because it's a misnomer and a complication, but they seem to be in no hurry. By the looks of it, what Notepad+? call ANSI is actually code page 1252 in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings differ on [Unicode Normalization](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) (demonstrated merely for relevant characters):

```
Form   String Unicode                        Length
----   ------ -------                        ------
(raw)  à à    \u00e0 \u0061\u0300            4
FormC  à à    \u00e0 \u00e0                  3
FormD  à à    \u0061\u0300 \u0061\u0300      5
FormKC à à    \u00e0 \u00e0                  3
FormKD à à    \u0061\u0300 \u0061\u0300      5
```

The former string is

- `T` (U+0054,  *Latin Capital Letter T*)
- `h` (U+0068,  *Latin Small Letter H*)
- `à` (U+00E0,  *Latin Small Letter A With Grave*)
- `n` (U+006E,  *Latin Small Letter N*)
- `h` (U+0068,  *Latin Small Letter H*)

while the latter one is

- `T` (U+0054,  *Latin Capital Letter T*)
- `h` (U+0068,  *Latin Small Letter H*)
- `a` (U+0061,  *Latin Small Letter A*)
- `̀` (U+0300,  *Combining Grave Accent*)
- `n` (U+006E,  *Latin Small Letter N*)
- `h` (U+0068,  *Latin Small Letter H*)

You invoke a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
print('Thành\nThành'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252'))
```

> ```
> ThÃ nh
> ThaÌ€nh
> ```

Comment: If Notepad++ had a proper Unicode implementation, it would deal with different normalizations and find both matches. It's probably not the only software with this limitation though.

Comment: @Codo I agree, and (for an advanced text editor) I'd expect at least something like `☐ Match Unicode Normalization Forms` check box (similar to and along with `☐ Match case`) in the **Find** dialogue. Strange enough, `python -c "print('Thành' == 'Thành')"` return `False` while (in contrast to) `pwsh -nopro -c "& {'Thành' -eq 'Thành'}"` -> `True`.